# WIF correlation with AuthorizeAttribute in MVC for access restriction to certain pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wif

In my MVC application I'm using WIF. I've added STS reference using Visual Studio built-in tool. FedUtil has generated some entries in web.config:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Social.Core.Security.RolesAwareClaimsAuthenticationManager, Social.Core" />
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://app.something.com/" />
      </audienceUris>
...
```

As you can see, additionally I've written custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager to add some claims to those already received from STS.

Nevertheless, in the application I have restricted page:

```
public class ProfileController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        // restricted area
    }
}
```

I've added AuthorizeAttribute on the restricted action. I need authentication only while entering *app.something.com/profile/index*. Unfortunately, now logon form shows while entering any part of the application, for example main page *app.something.com*.

How to correlate WIF authentication with AuthorizeAttribute and only authorize what I need ? Maybe I need to add app.something.com/profile/index somewhere in web.config or in STS ? Any clues ?

Comment: are you sure that `[Authorize]` attribute is causing the issue? remove it and does the problem occur?

Comment: I don't know if you catch clearly what I'm asking about. Mabye my question is not clear. I'd like to just make it working with this attribute (fire logon form served by WIF while accessing action with this attribute) or at least restrict access to particular page - not whole site, in any other way without this attribute.

Comment: i'm implying that that particular attribute is not causing your main page to require authentication. something else is doing it, like woloski suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the Add STS reference, the wizard will add the authotization section and deny anonymous users. Remove that.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```